# Recursive alghoritm to create a dynamic menu using Primefaces 3.5

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, menuitem, submenu

I need to create a dynamic menu in my jsf page using Primefaces 3.5.
I'm trying since 1 week to build a recursive alghoritm but seems too hard to build because the time is strength etc...
Also, every day I try to think a new alghoritm to create this without a good result...
I'm using JSF with Primefaces 3.5 and I can build a menubar using MenuItem and Submenu.

PS: The menu, could be have infinite submenu...

My Db table for submenu is the follow:

[image]

The result, should be as follow:

[image]

This is my java ManagedBean:

```
...
MenuModel model = new DefaultMenuModel();

@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
     //I retrieve data from DB (select *)

     //I need to create my recursive alghoritm here
}
```

In my Java ManagedBean, i retrieve all table data and I need to elaborate this data to build my menu.
The parent_id column is built to link the current item within an other item. So, if you have more than parent_id with the same value, the id equals to the parent_id will be a submenu.
The image result shown as the menu should be...

Can you help me please?

Comment: Are you sure about this approach? It will not be possible to issue complex reporting queries with this approach even though the recursive menu is built somehow dynamically (building a menu is merely one of several other things within an application). It goes beyond how modern RDBMS works.

Comment: I might agree with you...but unfortunately I have not designed this approach and I'm working in according with functional and technical specifications... :(